# How to transfer a ListView item on another ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

Okay it goes like this. I have two classes that extends ListFragments, both are initialized on   class extending FragmentActivity.

My question is

> How can I, when I select an item on ListView1, transfer that item to ListView2 and display it? Then removing the selected item from ListView1.

Example:

ListView1 have 3 items:

1. Dog
2. Cat
3. Mouse

Initially ListView2 is empty. Then when i Select the "Dog" From ListView1, it will be moved/transferred to ListView2 and "Dog" will be removed from ListView1.

THanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must create a Listview2 in Listview1(if ListItem1 clicked open listview2).

Comment: + if you can create listview with images,there is no problem in listview 2

Comment: how would I create ListView2 in ListView1? Is that even good a programming practice?

Answer (score 0):

When an item is selected in your first ListView, you need to simply retrieve the item from the adapter of the first ListView and add it to the adapter of the second ListView.

In practice, using fragments, this process will be slightly more complex as you will need to implement communication between the fragments (usually via the activity).

Comment: can i use an interface to communicate the two Fragments?